# XCode 4.5 (only) Loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

Downloaded the GM seed of Xcode 4.5/iOS 6 and I'm getting "Loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set" when I try to access one of my subclasses of `UITableViewController`.

In XCode 4.3.2 (the main version I have installed), the XIB's "Custom Class" is `UITableView` and the File's Owner view is set to the parent `UITableView`.

In XCode 4.5 GM seed, the XIB's "Custom Class" is `UIView` and the File's Owner view is NOT set.

When I set the File's Owner view and change the classes of the views back to what they are in XCode 4.3.2, my `UITableView` doesn't display correctly.  There is no error, but none of the fields on the `UITableView` are being populated correctly.

Previous questions related to this have been brushed off as "4.5/iOS 6 are in beta. Try it later", but now iOS 6 is due to be released soon, and we need to make sure our app works with it.

Suggestions?

---

**Edit:**

So what's actually being done is this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lighterBlue];     

    // show an indicator that we're loading info from the service
    [self presentLoadingView];

    // calls out to web service
    [[WebServiceManager sharedWebServiceManager] fetchInformationFromServiceWithString:string withSuccessBlock:^(NSDictionary *response)
    {
        NSDictionary *response = [response valueForKeyPath:@"PathName"];
        [variableThatPopulatesTable = [response valueForKey:[[response allKeys]objectAtIndex:0]]retain];

        // ignore this line
        [self buildArrays];

        // this is where it should be (and was, before iOS 6) populating the table
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }
    andCompletionBlock:^(NSDictionary *response)
    {
        [self dismissLoadingView];
    }];

}
```

In the `UITableView`, there are labels (which correctly display) and then fields that another method (`populateUI`) populates, and it populates from that `variableThatPopulatesTable` instance variable. But all of the fields in the `UITableView` are just empty.

Comment: Seeing as the view outlet was somehow disconnected, are you sure the delegate and data source outlets are connected?

Comment: They're not, but they aren't populated in Xcode 4.3.2 either. I looked at all the connections and attributes of the XIB in both 4.3.2 and 4.5 and I have them set exactly the same now.

Comment: Ok, having ruled that out, what exactly do you mean with "none of the fields on the UITableView are being populated correctly". They don't show up, they are not populated at all or populated with wrong data?

Comment: OK, I'll explain what is actually being done in an edit to the description.